# Azure VPN Gateway - Connections with BGP and without BGP

Tags: azure

a short Question about VPN Gateway with active BGP Settings.

I would like to connect 10 Local Network Gateways with Azure. 2 of this Connections with BGP and the Other 8 with normale static Routes.

Must i use two Gateways for this use case or can i activate the BGP Settings on the Gateway and can decide if i want to use BGP on the local Connection or not?

So can i use the same VPN Gateway for BGP Connections and VPN Connections without BGP?

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BGP is supported on all Azure VPN Gateway   Without BGP, you can still use your on-premises VPN equipment and the Azure VPN gateways. It works in a similar way to utilizing static routes (without BGP)

Yes, you turn on the BGP settings on the gateway and use BGP for local connections in same VPN Gateway

For your Reference :

[About BGP with Azure VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-bgp-overview)

[Configure active-active VPN gateways using the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/active-active-portal)